# Tomcat Parrellel Deployment Naming

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat8

When deploying to Apache Tomcat 8.5 on rhel Linux using the Parrallel deployment pattern.  We are running into an issue where the webapp started to deploy but then is undeployed right away.

The original war file foo.war was deployed, then we started deploying using this new way deploying the next app as foo##3.0.9.war and all was fine.  The next deployment was foo##3.0.10.war but that did not work.  We also renamed the file to foo##3010.war and that did not work.

foo.war // original war

foo##3.0.9.war // next release

foo##3.0.10.war // current release - did not deploy using parrallel deployment pattern

I would have expected that 3.0.10 > 3.0.9 and the app would have deployed, or at the very least 3010 > 3.0.9, but none of these variations worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation further [Parrallel Deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) it compares string literals.  9 > 1 so our 3.0.9 release was greater than our 3.0.10 release.  We are going to be reworking out deployment script to pad the last number to 3 places.  Will fix our problem.

Comment: Or start your patch level at `10` :p

Comment: FYI - Improving this is on the TODO list.